# Angular 2+ Role Permissions

Tags: angular, user-permissions

I'm currently making a small project using Angular 6 to practice some client-server interaction which is a simple blog-style site where users can view other's posts and make their own as well. So far I've tackled JWT auth and route guards to prevent someone not logged in from viewing protected resources.

The way the project is currently structured is so each user has a user profile displayed by a `ProfilePage` component. In my router I navigate to the correct user page with the structure `/user/:username` where `:username` is the specific user page the server will send back appropriate data for. The problem I am trying to solve is how I can make it so a user logged into their account can only add and delete posts on their profile page and not someone else's.

I've read up on user permissions and roles, however if both user's have a role of "USER", how can I differentiate when the user is looking at their page or not?

Some ideas I've had:

1. Dynamically check permissions on the page when the user navigates to it, so I would send a request to the server (with JWT bearer) and it would send back a user/editor role status for the page and then when the user posts something, the server would verify again that the user is allowed to post before actually making the changes in the back end.
2. Another Idea I had was to make a separate MyProfile Component that acts, looks, and feels like the user profile, except with editor buttons. The issue I can see with this though is I would later run into trouble when I implement an ADMIN role who can remove posts of any user (ethics aside for educational purposes of this project).
3. Similar to the first idea, but when the user logs in, note their username and just check that permission on the client side, then also on the server side when they actually make/delete a post to verify they are actually allowed to do that.

Do any of these options seem like a viable way to move forward? If I can do this still with a Guard, how so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will go for your solution 3.

In fact you don't even need to store your user's username when they login. As you are adopting JWT authorization in your application, you should store the JWT token instead (you don't even need to manually store it if it's set in your cookies upon login).

Your JWT token shall include very basic information (perhaps username or UUID, and others that you see appropriate) about your user as well as the token information. You should use this JWT token to retrieve user information from your backend when your user is accessing the profile page. (i.e. Attach this JWT bearer token in the authorization header, or to include it in the cookies. Your backend shall read this JWT token and retrieve the an unique identifier (username / uuid as suggested) to retrieve the user information)

When the user is about to update the user information, your should attach the JWT bearer token again and the backend should invalidate requests as needed.

I'd also recommend to just enable the `/user` route, or something like a `/myprofile` route for regular users. The `/user/:username` route shall only be opened to those who have the authority to view others' profile, says the admin.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, using the JWT for the username does give me that functionality practically for free!

Answer (score 0):

I would put the user's own profile page in its own route, not in the same route as others'. This way you can provide all the security (server side) on the personal, private profile page, whilest others' profile pages would be a public page stripped of any way to edit, delete, add, etc.